# Formula field (Checkbox) on case to be checked if Account selected on case has a picklist value checked

Tags: formula-field

I have a checkbox on Account 'Is Migrated'.

I have a checkbox on Case 'Account is Migrated'.

Using Lookup Account is selected in case. (Case has a lookup to account).

If the Account selected has checkbox 'Is Migrated' as checked then the formula field (Checkbox) 'Account is Migrated' must be checked.

I tried these 3 in formula field.

```
IF (Account.Is_Migrated__c == TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)

Account.Is_Migrated__c

Account.Is_Migrated__c == TRUE
```

But none of them worked. How to achieve this.

Comment: Bhoppesh, are you using the standard Account lookup field in the case or you have a custom lookup field ?.. also can you check the Field level Security of the checkbox field in the Account to see if you have access to read the value of the field ?

Comment: I am using custom Account Looup Field.

Comment: why you need a custom account lookup field in case object as we have a standard account lookup field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bhoopesh,
if you are using custom account lookup field, please use the custom field name in your formula instead of the standard account field..

change your formula to

```
YourCustomAccountFieldName__r.Is_Migrated__c
```

but I suggest you to use the existing standard account lookup field in the case object to link the case to an account instead of haivng your own custom lookup field..

Answer (score 1):

The formulas look all right.

Maybe the `Account` lookup field is not filled (but another custom lookup field to Account might?), or you don't have the proper rights to read either the `Account` or the `Is_Migrated__c` field on `Account`.